# Rasgo Error - Dataset with fqtn does not exist or this API key does not have access

Tags: python

I am trying to use `rasgo.get.dataset(fqtn='vw_orders_main')` but I am getting an error.

`APIError: Dataset with fqtn 'vw_orders_main' does not exist or this API key does not have access.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `rasgo.get.dataset()`, you can either:

- pass in a dataset_id
  `rasgo.get.dataset(123)`
- pass in a fully qualified table name (fqtn)
  `rasgo.get.dataset(fqtn="DB.SCHEMA.TABLE")`
- pass in a resource_key
  `rasgo.get.dataset(resource_key='mykey')`

From the appearance of the string you are using, I believe that is a resource key.

If you are using a variable called `vw_orders_main` to hold the FQTN string, then try it without the single quotes.

Examples:

```
vw_orders_main = "DB.SCHEMA.TABLE"
rasgo.get.dataset(fqtn=vw_orders_main)
```

or

```
rasgo.get.dataset(fqtn="DB.SCHEMA.TABLE")
```

or, if what you meant was resource_key,

```
rasgo.get.dataset(resource_key='vw_orders_main')
```

A resource_key is randomly assigned when a dataset is published, unless you specify the string yourself (like it appears that you did). It provides you the ability to tie multiple datasets as 1, thus allowing “versions”.

Resource Links: [get dataset](https://docs.rasgoml.com/rasgo-docs/reference/pyrasgo/methods/rasgo.get.dataset), [publish dataset](https://docs.rasgoml.com/rasgo-docs/reference/pyrasgo/methods/rasgo.publish.dataset)